# Single Value range is not allowed in packed dimension

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog, vivado, simulink

I have been reading about packed and unpacked dimensions in systemverilog  from https://www.chipverify.com/systemverilog/systemverilog-arrays, in the following code I just want to use a memory array of 64 bits width and 256 depth. This will be used in a testbench in vivado simulator.

So far, I have used many combinations on how to define the memory but always I get the same syntax error: **single value range is not allowed in packed dimension**, displayed is my final attempt. could you please tell me what is the issue here?

```
      bit [63:0] tab [256];
   
      tab[0] = 64'h30000000000000FF;  //RX
      tab[1] = 64'h80000000000000FF;  //TX
      tab[2] = 64'h00000000000000FF;  //SW
      tab[3] = 64'hC0000000000000FF;  //LP
      ...
```

Comment: I will accept Tom's answer, however the issue was that "tab" was instantiated inside the "initial begin" which caused vivado to complain with  that syntax error message, then the other question would be why vivado did that which don't know. My syntax described in the question was accepted by the simulator too.

Comment: Is your file .sv or .v in Vivado?

Comment: @Mitu Raj the file in vivado is a .sv (systemverilog). It was a silly mistake but it was the error message that throw me off.

Comment: So how did you fix it??? Because the syntax looks correct to me.

Comment: @MituRaj the syntax shown in the post is ok but if you declare all that code between the `initial begin` and `end` for this particular case using vivado tool, you get that syntax error, it was a silly mistake but the error legend was throwing me off trying to initialize the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
bit [63:0] tab [256];
```

Your second dimension is not a range, so if the syntax were valid, it would be trying to declare a single 64-bit value called `tab`.

The correct syntax is:

```
bit [63:0] tab [255:0];
```

Which is an array of 256 x 64-bit values

Comment: thank you, however  vivado still complaining same syntax error, I kind of believe it is vivado systemverilog  does not support this unpacked/packed arrays. I may need to ask xilinx.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "declare a single 64-bit value".  The OP code declares a variable with 256 64-bit values, as seen on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/hyeJ).